# How to use a class inside a named module that is in seperate file? Throws ReferenceError: module is not defined

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2015, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a simple Node.js console app using TypeScript ECMAScript6 using Visual Studio 2015 community edition and not able to use a class defined inside a module in app.ts. Visual studio does however displays the module "DataModels" as namespace and also the class in intellisense, but it throws an error while initializing it in app.ts

Error: ReferenceError: DataModels is not defined

Tried VS project settings using AMD and CommonJs as module system but no luck.

Folder structure

```
/
 app.ts
 DataModels.ts
 Scripts
  Typings (dir)
   Node   (dir)
    node.d.ts
```

app.ts

```
/// <reference path="DataModels.ts" />
var user: IUser = new DataModels.User();
user.Name = 'user1';
console.log(user.Name);
```

DataModels.ts

```
interface IUser {
    Name: string;
    Email: string;
    UserName: string;
    Password: string;
    ProfilePicPath: URL;

}

module DataModels {

    export class User implements IUser {
        private _name: string;
        private _email: string;
        private _username: string;
        private _password: string;
        private _profilePicPath: URL;

        public get Name() {
            return this._name;
        }
        public set Name(value) {
            this._name = value;
        }

        public get Email() {
            return this._email;
        }
        public set Email(value) {
            this._email = value;
        }

        public get UserName() {
            return this._username;
        }
        public set UserName(value) {
            this._username = value;
        }

        public get Password() {
            return this._password;
        }
        public set Password(value) {
            this._password = value;
        }

        public get ProfilePicPath() {
            return this._profilePicPath;
        }
        public set ProfilePicPath(value) {
            this._profilePicPath = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tried VS project settings using AMD and CommonJs as module system but no luck.

Your code won't work with any module system since it's not written in external module format, it will only work if you compile your project into a single file. Now, assuming you do want to use a module system of some sort here's how you should write your code to work with AMD/CommonJS etc:

**app.ts**

```
// note the lack of reference paths
import * as DataModels from './DataModels';

var user: DataModels.IUser = new DataModels.User();
user.Name = 'user1';
console.log(user.Name);
```

**DataModels.ts**

```
export interface IUser {
  ...
}

export class User implements IUser {
  ...
}
```

Comment: import * gave runtime error ",CnsoleApp2\DataModels.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { class User {
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet sup
ported outside strict mode. Keyword 'class' was highlighted.

Comment: // must not use module name to import as..
// instead use a new name like below:

import * as ModuleDataModels from './DataModels';

var user: ModuleDataModels.IUser = new ModuleDataModels.User();
user.Name = 'user1';
console.log(user.Name);

Comment: Put `"use strict";` at the top of your source files, this is done automatically in TypeScript 1.8, so I guess you're on an older version.